# How can I put a logo in the reports generated by jasmine reporters?

Tags: npm, jasmine, protractor

I want to include a logo at the top corner of the screen in the reports generated by jasmine reporters ?
How can I customised the report ?

Comment: What package of reporter do you use? What is the exact name of this reporter? You can download `protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter` if you are testing Angular website.

Comment: I am using protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter.

Comment: In `index.js` you can add img to `openReportTemplate` variable

Comment: What exactly do I need to include in openReportTemplate to include an image to the top-left of the report ? I am not versed with CSS. I am editing in protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/index.js file.

Comment: @AYa .. I have provided a solution below. It will add an image to the HTML report ..  And regarding placing it at the exact position/style that you want .. it should be easy ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `index.js` (located [here](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js)) which has the `printResults(suite)` method - (located [here](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js#L363)) that constructs the HTML.

I tried adding an image just above the list of tests and it looks good.

```
function printResults(suite) {

    //Output generation starts here. Header is constructed above
    var output = '';
    if (suite.isPrinted || !hasValidSpecs(suite)) {
      return '';
    }
    suite.isPrinted = true;

    // I added it here just above the list of tests. Its upto you how you want to do it
    output += '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">' + '<ul style="list-style-type:none">';
```

Sample HTML Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. But if this project is cloned by someone else and he does the npm install on his machine, then he won't be able to view the report in the way I will see with my modified index,js file.

Comment: Yeah, thats true .. And may be we have to live with that ..  or you can create a private npm module ,package it and share it across .. I am not an expert on npm stuff .. May be posting another question tagging npm group will get the best answer

Comment: @AYa I'd raise an issue with the `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` project and ask for this feature to be built-in. And, if you fork and implement it in a generic fashion, you can send the Pull Request and make the project better and the world a better place to live in :)

Comment: @AdityaReddy With the existing configurations, whenever I run my specs again, the results of those are appended in the original html report and If I set preservedirectory to false then I will get my report in a random file whereIn I will not be able to pre-put my image before I test my files. Any, idea on how to deal with it ?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you ... You will be adding the image to `index.js` right .. so any new report being generated will contain the image right? ..

Comment: If I run the tests again, then a new report should be generated whereas now the results is being appended in the same report and I am getting duplicate entries of the tests results. Also, not sure if this would be the right approach as -  if someone else clones my project then he won't copy the node modules na. ? He will install it using 'npm install', so these changes that I have done in Index.js will not reflect in his and thus, his report won't include images.

Comment: Totally agree .. if some one else does a fresh npm install or even clones the project from git. .he will not see your changes ... Then only way to go foward is with the approach suggested by @alecxe .. to raise an issue with corresponding team and get it added into original repo

Comment: And regarding results being appended .. I guess there are options provided by reporter config to clear them every time you run .. it will only clear the reported generated last time and your index.js will still contain the changes you made and on a fresh run .. you should see good results